# iMessages - can one disable 'join/leave' messages in group chats?

Tags: notifications, messages, chat

Does anyone know where you can disable the join/leave messages in group chats in iMessages? In low-traffic chats it's utterly annoying to have scrollbacks full of 'xxx joined the chat.'/'yyy left the chat.'

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that your talking about WhatsApp? Not the "Messages" app. Are you talking about iPhone, iPad, Macs?

Comment: Nah, not WhatsApp, Messages on Mac :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this isn't possible, I checked the iPhone, iPad and Mac version but this setting is nowhere to be found.
As for changing it through terminal or fiddling with program files, that will only change the setting on the mac.

Answer (score -1):

[Adium](https://adium.im/) is a much better IM client and allows one to toggle viewing the join/leave messages.
(no idea about iPhone client, though).

[[image: See the Show/Hide option]

Comment: This is a question about iMessages.

Comment: @Marc - yes, and we'd already established that it's not possible, so, amen. What I was offering was a viable (and free) alternative, which actually turned out to be a good solution for myself when I was faced with the same problem.  Thanks for the negative vote, though, I guess that'll teach me about trying to help others.